# What is the difference between using params[:foo] and @foo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
ApplicationController
before_action :example_filter 

def example_filter 
  params[:foo] = '1' if #somethinghere
  @foo         = '1' if #somethinghere
end

NewsController

if @foo         == '1' #somethinghere
if params[:foo] == '1' #somethinghere
```

What are the differences or benefits between using @foo or params[:foo] in this situation?

One difference is that the user could pass params[:foo] themselves in the query string:

> example.com/news?foo=1

Comment: The `@foo` is object member. The `params[:foo]` is request param. The `params[:foo]` - may be only string. The `params[:foo] = 1` is overwriting request params. Better to use `@foo = params[:foo]` and than `@foo = '1' if...`.

Comment: @oklas please consider submitting that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@foo` is object member.
The `params[:foo]` is request param.
The `params[:foo]` - may not have objects it may be only string or array of string (because it brought from request).

The code `params[:foo] = 1` which you write is overwriting request params.

Better to use code like this:

```
ApplicationController
before_action :example_filter 

def example_filter 
  @foo = params[:foo] 
  @foo = 'something' if #somethinghere
end

# somewhere    
if @foo == '1' #somethinghere
```